# Is ToLocalTime broken on Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin

I'm running the following code in Xamarin Studio (v4.0.12 - Mono 3.2.3) in GMT timeszone...

```
var utcDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 07, 15, 15, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string utcTimeString = utcDateTime.ToLongTimeString();
string localTimeString = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime().ToLongTimeString();
```

... but both variables return the value "3:00:00 PM".

If I run the same code under .NET 4.0 then the second variable is "4:00:00 PM". This is what I would expect.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, should this not be identical in both?

The DateTime returned from 'ToLocalTime()'  appears identical to the original except that the 'Kind' is now 'Local'.

**UPDATE:**

This is definitely related to the year in the above example. If the current year is entered then the times are different (and correct), if anything before 1970 is entered then the timezone is ignored.

Here's a copy of my timezone information based on the code in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx

```
Standard time name:           GMT
Daylight saving time name:    BST

Current date and time:        2013-10-02 09:27
Daylight saving time?         True
Coordinated Universal Time:   2013-10-02 08:27
UTC offset:                   01:00:00

Daylight saving time for year 1970:
0001-01-01 00:00 to 0001-01-01 00:00, delta: 00:00:00

1970
7/15/1970 3:00:00 PM
7/15/1970 3:00:00 PM

2005
7/15/2005 3:00:00 PM
7/15/2005 4:00:00 PM

Now
10/2/2013 8:27:09 AM
10/2/2013 9:27:09 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

By checking `DateTime` source code of Mono, we can see the `ToLocalTime` call uses `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` to perform the conversion,

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs

Thus, to troubleshoot this issue you meet, you might print out `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` in both cases (iOS and Windows) to see if there is any significant difference.

The Windows case is correct, because .NET 4 accesses the underlying Windows system to locate the proper timezone (with full DST support).

The Xamarin.iOS case is difficult, as we are not sure whether iOS exposes the correct time zone information and whether Xamarin.iOS consumes it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround extension method

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToLocalTimeX(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var info = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        return dateTime.Add(info.BaseUtcOffset.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(info.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now) ? 1 : 0)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're off by summer time.

GMT is pretty much the same as UTC (GMT is solar-based while UTC is atomic-clock based), but since neither has summer time they should for all intents and purposes be identical.

The problem is likely that you're not using GMT on your Windows machine, but instead some other summer-time-aware timezone.

Comment: I'm in the UK currently under BST (GMT +1) and my windows machine is set correctly.

Comment: My question is that Mono should also be timezone aware but doesn't appear to be. Both mono and .net report the current SummerTime timezone is BST

Comment: I get the correct offset for my TZ (Central US), 5 hours behind GMT.

Comment: @ChrisKoiak: You said you're in GMT in your initial post, not BST/GMT+1 - please print out TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName for both machines to ensure you're using the same TZ.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the timezone info. Hopefully this will make it clearer, thanks for your help so far

Comment: This is probably a linux/unixism then, since dates are typically represented as a period of time since 1970.

Comment: but surely people need to represent and convert UTC dates from before 1970? I've emailed Xamarin support directly and will update this thread with any conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

While a fix is being worked on for this bug, you can use this workaround for DateTime.ToLocalTime():

Datetime localdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (utcdate, TimeZoneInfo.Utc,
TimeZoneInfo.Local);

Comment: As mentioned at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15134#c6 this workaround doesn't work